# How to monitor all changes by application?

Tags: windows, filesystems, registry, hook

I recently downloaded an application and am very interested in its workings. It heavily relies on making changes to registry/filesystem/user accounts and processes. I am looking for software that will monitor the application for all changes. I know I could create my  own global hook to monitor but I assume there is most likely some good software for this purpose. Can anyone.make any recomendations? I know sandboxes and antivirus applications can show basic filesystem and registry but I would like something a little more advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) by SysInternals.